# PHP: break file into lines only if they end with commas

Tags: php

I have a PHP api that receives an uploaded .sql file and needs to break it into single queries and execute them one by one.

I tried doing

```
$queries = file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
```

The problem is that the file can contain queries written on multiple lines that would get broken. So I tried

```
$queries = explode( ';'.PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) );
```

The problem is now that PHP_EOL represents the end of line symbols for the server system, and the uploaded file may represent new lines in a different way.

**How can I reliably break an .sql file content into an array of queries?**

Comment: Why do you use PHP_EOL? You can trim your queries later.

Comment: You could try `preg_split('/;\R/', file_get_contents(...))`, `\R` matches any newline sequence

Comment: @tanaydin sorry if I wasn't clear, I need to explicitly distinguish ";"+"newline" because a query could contain a ";" for other reasons (ie: an insert into a varchar column)

Comment: Oh I see now, @Nick's solution could work.